# [myapp]:showAsAction="always" error when using appcompat

Tags: android, menuitem, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

In my menu.xml file I used to have:

```
[myapp]:showAsAction="always"
```

and it alwas worked. But since i target API 20 I get the following error:

> Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library

I have the appcompat library included in the build path. When I change it to:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

the menu item doesn't show up in the Actionbar

Comment: Looks like disabling check is workaround for now...

Answer (score 0):

add this to Oncreate method:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```